# How to update ContentControl UI when custom property change on design time?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp

I have make a `ContentControl` and it has some custom `Propertities`. The control itself works fine but I like to update its interface during design time in XAML editor. The problem is next: The control's UI update if I change its `Size` (`SizeChanged event` will do that) but I cannot find any way to do this if `CustomProperty` like `OffsetX` changes during design time.

So, how to change the following code to make this happen? It isn't too convenient to update Control UI changing its size every time.

```
public sealed class MyControlElement: ContentControl
{
    //
    //SOME INITIALIZE CODE IS HERE
    //

    public MyControlElement() => DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControlElement);

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        //
        //SOME INITIALIZE CODE IS HERE
        //

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    //OFFSET X DESCRIPTION 
    [Description("OffsetX"), Category("MyControlElementParameters"), Browsable(true)]
    //OFFSET X
    public int OffsetX
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(OffsetXProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (OffsetX != value)
            {
                SetValue(OffsetXProperty, value);
                OnOffsetXChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OffsetX", typeof(int), typeof(MyControlElement), PropertyMetadata.Create(0));
    public event EventHandler OffsetXChanged;
    private void OnOffsetXChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateControlUI();
        this.OffsetXChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try attaching an event handler with DependencyProperty: new PropertyMetadata(0, OnOffsetXChanged))

Comment: Bilal, Unfortunately this one didn't work in design time.

Comment: Hello, XAML Designer is a relatively static preview interface. The UI changes you make to your custom controls can be changed by rebuild the project, but some dynamic changes (such as SizeChanged) require you to run the app to view it.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Code behind does not work at design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some kind of "Hack". Still hoping to find better solution. The next trick works and it is possible to update `Control` interface during design time.

First need to add handler for `Loaded`.

```
    public MyControlElement()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControlElement);
        this.Loaded += MyControlElement_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyControlElement_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        //SOME INITIALIZE CODE HERE IF NEEDED
        //
        //RUN CONTROL VISUAL UPDATER ONLY IF IN DESIGN MODE
        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled) ControlDesignTimeUIUpdater();
        //FLAG - CONTROL HAS BEEN INITIALIZED
        IsControlInitialized = true;
    }
```

And lets add `ControlDesignTimeUIUpdater` void for UI update. This `void` has a loop to keep UI updated during design time.

```
    private async void ControlDesignTimeUIUpdater()
    {
        double OldImageWidth = ImageWidth;
        double OldImageHeight = ImageHeight;
        CornerRadius OldImageCornerRadius = ImageCornerRadius;
        double OldBorderThickness = BorderThickness;
        ImageSource OldMyImageSource = MyImageSource;

        while (this.IsLoaded)
        {
            //CHECK CHANGES DELAY 100ms
            await Task.Delay(100);
            //MAKE SURE CONTROL IS INITIALIZED BEFORE ANY UI UPDATES
            if (IsControlInitialized)
            {
                if (OldImageWidth != ImageWidth)
                {
                    OldImageWidth = ImageWidth;
                    SetImageWidth();
                }
                if (OldImageHeight != ImageHeight)
                {
                    OldImageHeight = ImageHeight;
                    SetImageHeight();
                }
                if (OldImageCornerRadius != ImageCornerRadius)
                {
                    OldImageCornerRadius = ImageCornerRadius;
                    SetImageCornerRadius();
                }
                if (OldBorderThickness != BorderThickness)
                {
                    OldBorderThickness = BorderThickness;
                    SetBorderThickness();
                }
                if (OldMyImageSource != MyImageSource)
                {
                    OldMyImageSource = MyImageSource;
                    SetMyImageSource();
                }
                //
                // ETC.
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

By this `Hack` it is possible update control in "real-time" during design. It's even possible add `animations`, size changes etc.